# Need help to derive the Complexity!

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, communication-complexity

Please help me regarding this one! What will be the communication and computation complexity of this code??

```
While (m>0) do
{
   While ((m mod 2)==0) do
       {
          m ← ⌊m/2⌋ 
         //parties communicate m times;
       }
m = m – 1;
}
```

This code been modified from the book "Fundamental of computer algorithm" by Sahni.So according to that, it seemed computational complexity is O(*logm*) as m decreases by a factor of at least 2. But can i say communication complexity is O(*logm*) as well?? Probably not; i'm really confused!!

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help you understand things but we're not here to solve homework exercises for you.

Comment: @david Richerby-I've already cleared my misconception. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $m > 0$ is even then the two parties communicate $m/2$ times at their first round of communication. If $m > 1$ is odd then they communicate $(m-1)/2$ times at their first round of communication. In particular, the communication complexity is not $O(\log m)$, but at least $\Omega(m)$. In fact, it is also $O(m)$, but you'll have to figure out why yourself.